# Creating and Passing of mxArray Data from other functions to Mex gateway function

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Ok guys, I feel as if I'm falling into the rabbit hole...

To build an interface as a Matlab-Mex that receives several different messages which consist of complicated C-structs, I want to create the corresponding Mex-Structs each in different functions.

Is it somehow possible to pass `mxArrays` that contain fields from user defined functions to the `mexFunction()`?

I created functions that should be called inside of `mexFunctions()` that should pass filled `mxArray`  Datatypes to the `mexFunction()` as pointers but that didn't work.

E.g.

```
mxArray* createFoo();
```

Or

```
void createFoo(mxArray* myData);
```

Inside the `mexFunction()` these `createFoo()` functions couldn't pass the created data pointers back to the function. Inside them, creating of data did work, but the pointers they returned changed mysteriously because of e.g. `myData = mxCreateDoubleMatrix()`.

The Compiler is Visual Studio 2010, Matlab is 2011b.

It would be possible to directly write to workspace inside the functions, but that is very bad style.

Comment: So, do you want at the end of the call `createFoo` to have the argument point to a correct data structure?

Comment: I want to create the correct mx-data structure in createFoo() and return a correct pointer to that datastructure, so that it can be passed from mexFunction() to Matlab.

Comment: You need to show more code, but it probably didn't work because if you want to modify a pointer inside a function you need to pass it as either a `**` or a reference (`*&`).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you create data in createFoo and how you use it or check in mexFunction?

Comment: Let me see if I get it right: you define `mxArray* createFoo() {return mxCreateDoubleMatrix(); }`, and when you call it in your `mexFunction()`, the returned pointer is corrupt? Hopefully you don't call `mxDestroyArray()` on your pointer before returning the pointer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should never again ask a question without a minimal example. The simple problem was, that I forgot to `return` the `*mxArray`...

Both possibilities to pass the `mxArray` work as they should:

**A) Return mxArray***

```
mxArray* createFoo()
{
    mxArray* myArray;

    myArray = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    *mxGetPr(myArray) = 3;

    mexPrintf("*mxGetPr(myArray)= %f\n", *mxGetPr(myArray)); // 3

    return myArray;
}
```

**B) Reference mxArray** **

```
void createFooReference(mxArray** myArray)
{
    *myArray = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    *mxGetPr(*myArray) = 4;

    mexPrintf("Pointer: *mxGetPr(*myArray)= %f\n", *mxGetPr(*myArray)); // 4
}
```

Now it's possible to call the functions and return the values to Matlab:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray prhs[])
{
    mxArray *mexA, *mexB;

    mexA = createFoo();
    plhs[0] = mexA; // 3

    createFooReference(&mexB)
    plhs[1] = mexB; // 4
}
```